# JSHINT: The __proto__ property is deprecated

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, jshint

I'm using a "hasOwnProperty" function to extend compatibility but JSHint says that the Object.prototype.__proto__ is deprecated. There is a way to rewrite this function to avoid this warning and ensure the compatibility?

```
var hasOwnProperty = function (obj, prop) {
    var proto = obj.__proto__ || obj.constructor.prototype;
    return (prop in obj) &&
        (!(prop in proto) || proto[prop] !== obj[prop]);
};
```

Comment: why not just `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)`?

Comment: It's not deprecated. It's part of the current draft.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "correct" way to do what you're trying to do is to use the [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) function:

```
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
```

That's not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and below though so if you need to support old environments you could extend your test to include a check for that, and fall back to `__proto__` where necessary.

That will obviously not avoid the JSHint warning though so you'll probably still want to set the [`proto`](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#proto) option to turn it off.

Comment: `__proto__` isn't supported in IE 8 either, so no fallback necessary unless ancient webkit/firefox/opera support is required.

Answer (score 6):

If you wanted to avoid rewriting the code you could add the following to the top of your file. [It's one of the "relaxing" options in JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#proto) you can use to reduce the number of warnings you get:

```
/* jshint proto: true */
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for anyone authoring in ES 2015+. [It’s been standardized now.](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-additional-properties-of-the-object.prototype-object)